# Refactor to rethrow swallowed exceptions

Tags: c#, exception, resharper, automated-refactoring

I am working on a codebase that does an awful lot of exception swallowing, in most cases like this:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Is there a quick way, e.g. with resharper to add a throw to all of these? or at least break on message box show? Because all i get is a generic error message with no indication of where it is in the code..

I tried Resharper search with pattern but the minute I add "catch" it says the search is ambiguous

Comment: just remembered i could hit pause in the debugger...doi!

Comment: Another option is ["Break when exception is thrown"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx) It will break even when the exception is handled.

Comment: Tip: in the future, log all exceptions to the event viewer along with their stack trace. This will greatly help diagnose issues.

Comment: I agree @dcastro unfortunately this is an inherited code base

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper pattern search is great, but it is very syntax-driven. To match your `catch`, you'll need to include the `try` in the search.